# How many objects are created in this case?

Tags: java, string, object

The title says it all

```
String a;
String b = new String("Hello");
```

I've seen a lot of questions like this but none of them had Strings that weren't initiated yet.

Can someone help me on this ?

Thank you.

Comment: No. "I've seen a lot of questions like this but none of them had Strings that weren't initiated yet."

Comment: Just one, in the `String a` it is only declaring a variable `a` of type String.

Comment: @Ssiro is asking whether declaring a variable creates any `Object`, the answer is obviously no, it is only a reference without any target

Comment: Awesome, thanks. That's all I needed to know. Can one of you "Answer" the question so I can declare it solved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a single object that is referenced by variable `b`, `a` is a declared variable without any data assigned to it, that is not an object in a Java sense

Comment: to be exact: `b` is not an object, it is a reference referencing a `new String()`.

Comment: yes, but after the execution, you can call it object `b`, my wording might be confusing though

Comment: Calling `b` an object is going to end up in all sorts of confusion. Does `b = null;` delete an object? No, it doesn't it clears a reference - the object might still be alive and well.

Comment: Yeah, that I agree, sorry for the confusion, though that object will probably be shredded alive by gc

Answer (score 1):

First row only declares a string variable, but doesn't create object. In the second row, a string object is created with a `new` keyword.

So there's only one object created.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an explanation took from [OCA Java SE 7 Programmer I Certification Guide: Prepare for the 1ZO-803 exam](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1617291048):

> An object comes into the picture when you use the keyword operator new. 
>   You can initialize a reference variable with this object. Note the difference between declaring a variable and initializing it. The following is an example of a class Person and another class ObjectLifeCycle:

```
class Person {}
class ObjectLifeCycle {
    Person person;
}
```

> In the previous code, no objects of class Person are created in the class ObjectLife-Cycle; it declares only a variable of type Person. An object is created when a reference variable is initialized:

```
class ObjectLifeCycle2 {
    Person person = new Person();
}
```

> Syntactically, an object comes into being by using the new operator. Because
>   Strings can also be initialized using the = operator, the following code is a valid example of String objects being created

```
class ObjectLifeCycle3 {
    String obj1 = new String("eJava");
    String obj2 = "Guru";
}
```